# Show that $\lim_{p \to \infty} \| f \|_p = \| f \|_\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

In a space with measure $1$, $||f||_p$ is an increasing function with respect of $p$. To show that $\lim_{p \rightarrow \infty} ||f||_p=||f||_{\infty}$ we have to show that  $||f||_{\infty}$ is the supremum, right??

To show that, we assume that $||f||_{\infty}-\epsilon$ is the supremum.

From the essential supremum we have that $m(\{|f|>||f||_{\infty}-\epsilon\})=0$.

So, we have to show that $m(\{|f|>||f||_{\infty}-\epsilon\})>0$.

Let  $A=\{|f|>||f||_{\infty}-\epsilon\}$.

We have that $\int_A |f|^p \leq \int |f|^p \leq ||f||_{\infty}^p$.

$\int_A |f|^p >\int_A (||f||_{\infty}-\epsilon)^p=(||f||_{\infty}-\epsilon)^p m(A)$

So, $m(A)^{1/p} (||f||_{\infty}-\epsilon)<||f||_p \leq ||f||_{\infty}$

How could we continue to show that $m(A)>0$??

**EDIT:**

Is it as followed??

We have that $0<||f||_{\infty}-\epsilon<||f||_{\infty}$ for some $\epsilon>0$.

$||f||_{\infty}$ is the essential supremum. So, from the definition we have that $m\left ( \{|f(x)>||f||_{\infty}-\epsilon\} \right )>0$.

Let  $A=\{|f|>||f||_{\infty}-\epsilon\}$.

We have that $\int_A |f|^p \leq \int |f|^p \leq ||f||_{\infty}^p$.

$\int_A |f|^p >\int_A (||f||_{\infty}-\epsilon)^p=(||f||_{\infty}-\epsilon)^p m(A)$

So, $m(A)^{1/p} (||f||_{\infty}-\epsilon)<||f||_p \leq ||f||_{\infty}$

Taking the limit $p \rightarrow +\infty$ we have the following:

$$\lim_{p \rightarrow +\infty}m(A)^{1/p} (||f||_{\infty}-\epsilon)<\lim_{p \rightarrow +\infty} ||f||_p \overset{ m(A)>0 \Rightarrow \lim_{p \rightarrow +\infty}m(A)^{1/p}=1}{\Longrightarrow} \\ ||f||_{\infty}-\epsilon<\lim_{p \rightarrow +\infty} ||f||_p$$

Is this correct?? How do we conclude that $\lim_{p \rightarrow +\infty} ||f||_p=||f||_{\infty}$ ??

Comment: You know that $m(\{|f| > \|f\|_\infty - \epsilon\}) > 0$ by definition of $\|f\|_\infty$ as the smallest constant such that $m(\ldots) = 0$.

Comment: @AlexR I got stuck right now...Could you explain it further to me??

Comment: $$\|f\|_\infty = \mathop{\rm ess\;sup} \|f\| = \inf_{m(N) = 0} \sup_{x\notin N} |f(x)|$$
Should say it all, no? Note that $m(\{|f| > C\}) = 0 \Rightarrow C \ge \|f\|_\infty$ due to the $\inf$-part.

Comment: $||f||_p$ is increasing w.r.t $p$ in a space of measure $1$, but isn't your question asking about the general case?

Answer (score 3):

First of all you have to show that $||f||_\infty$ is a superior bound. But this is immediate by the definition of $\| \cdot\|_\infty$.

Now you want to show that, for all $\epsilon$ we have $$\lim_{p \rightarrow \infty} \|f\|_p > ||f||_\infty - \epsilon$$

As already observed and using your notation, $m(A) = m(|f| > ||f||_\infty -\epsilon)>0$. Now putting the things together you got

$$\|f\|_p > (||f||_\infty- \epsilon)m(A)^{1/p}$$ for all values of $p$. Now just take the limit, which exists since the sequence is increasing and bounded, to obtain what you desire.

Comment: Do you mean that it is as followed?? $$(||f||_{\infty}-\epsilon)\lim m(A)^{(1/p)}<\lim ||f||_p=||f||_{\infty}-\epsilon\Rightarrow lim m(A)^{(1/p)}=1\Rightarrow m(A)\neq 0$$

Comment: $m(A) > 0$ by the definition of $ess sup \|f\|$. You don't have to care about $m(A)$, since it is positive. You just have to show what I wrote above: $\lim_{p \rightarrow \infty} \|f\|_p > ||f||_\infty - \epsilon$. Because you already have that $\lim_{p \rightarrow \infty} \|f\|_p \le ||f||_\infty$.

Comment: Haven't we assumed that $m(A)=0$ and we want to find a conradiction, that means that we want to find that $m(A)>0$ ?? We assume, to get a contradiction, that $||f||_{\infty}-\epsilon$ is the supremum. Does that mean that the limit of $||f||_p$ when $p \rightarrow +\infty$ is equal to $||f||_{\infty}-\epsilon$ ??

Comment: $\|f\|_\|{\infty}$ is exactly what AlexR commented above. That definition implies that your set $A$ has positive measure. We don't want to prove $m(A) > 0$ we already know that from $\|f\|_{\infty}$. When you take the limit at both sides of the last inequality in may answer you get that $\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty} ||f||_p > \|f\|_{\infty} - \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon$... Did I make it clear?

Comment: Why does the definition imply that the set $A$ has positive measure?? Haven't we suppose that $||f||_{\infty}-\epsilon$ is the supremum?? Isn't the defintion of the essential supremum $$m\left ( \{|f|>||f||_{\infty}-\epsilon\}\right )=0$$ ??

Comment: AlexR's answer is exactly about this question. Just change $C$ in his answer by $\|f\|_{\infty} - \epsilon$

Comment: I edited my initial post... Could you tell me if it correct??

Comment: Yeeeeessss! That is it!

Comment: Ok!! Thanks a lot!!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The final step follows from the definition of the essential supremum.

> **Proposition**
>   If $m(\{|f| > C\}) = 0$ then necessarily $C \ge \|f\|_\infty$.

*Proof*
Let $N := \{|f|>C\}$. By assumption $m(N) = 0$. This means
$$\|f\|_\infty = \inf_{m(N') = 0} \sup_{x\notin N'} |f(x)| \le \sup_{x\notin N} |f(x)| = \sup_{\{|f| > C\}} |f(x)| \le C$$
as was to be shown.

Now use this proposition together with your initial steps to conclude a contradiction for $C = \|f\|_\infty - \epsilon < \|f\|_\infty$.

Comment: So, do we not show it in the way I started??

Comment: Unfortunately your estimates are "in the wrong direction", so yeah, you're out of luck with that start.

Comment: Could you explain me the following?? $$\|f\|_\infty = \inf_{m(N') = 0} \sup_{x\notin N'} |f(x)| \le \sup_{x\notin N} |f(x)| = \sup_{\{|f| > C\}} |f(x)| \le C$$

Comment: Since $m(N) = 0$ we know that $\{N' : m(N') = 0\}$ contains $N$, thus the infimum must be at most the value for a particular element:
$$\inf_{x\in S} f(x) \le f(x_0) \qquad\forall\ x_0\in S$$

Comment: I edited my initial post... Could you tell me if it correct??

Comment: @MaryStar That's okay. Now you showed that $\|f\|_\infty-\epsilon$  is a lower bound for the limit for all $\epsilon > 0$, i.e. $\lim \|f\|_p \ge \|f\|_\infty$. On the other hand it's an elementary estimate that $\|f\|_p \le \|f\|_\infty$ so $\lim\|f\|_p \le \|f\|_\infty$. Conclude equaltiy.

Comment: Ok!! Thank you very much!!! :-)

Comment: @MaryStar If this resolved you quesion, please consider marking it as answered.